# Passing JWKS to jwks-rsa npm package from lambda environment variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, rsa, node-modules

I have a AWS custom lambda authorizer configured on API gateway. Currently I am using Okta nodejs SDK which uses "https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa" jwks-rsa npm module internally to verify the signature of OAuth access token.

As per the documentation of this module I have to pass JWKS URI as the parameter to verify signature. PFB sample code -

```
const jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');

const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri: 'https://sandrino.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json',
  requestHeaders: {}, // Optional
  timeout: 30000 // Defaults to 30s
});

const kid = 'RkI5MjI5OUY5ODc1N0Q4QzM0OUYzNkVGMTJDOUEzQkFCOTU3NjE2Rg';
const key = await client.getSigningKey(kid);
const signingKey = key.getPublicKey();
```

It needs JWSK URL to be passed in as parameter. I could not find a way to pass these keys as json directly to this module. I will be storing the actual response of keys URL as env variable in Lambda function and would like to pass this variable to jwksClient to verify the signature. This will avoid HTTP call to JWKS URL from lambda.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So is this a Okta SDK question? A AWS Lambda question? What is the problem you try to fix? Any code you can share?

Comment: Hi @Jens this is actually npm package "https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa" related. Okta or even Auth0 nodejs SDKs use this same package internally to verify signature of OAuth token. I have updated the question with the code and desc.